# How to go along a numeric vector and mark the index of currently minimal value until finding a smaller one?

Tags: r, min

I want to obtain the indexes of minimal values such as:

```r
v1 <- c(20, 30, 5, 18, 2, 10, 8, 4)
```

The result is:

```r
1 3 5
```

Explanation:

Over `v1`, we start at value `20`. Without moving on, we note the minimal value (`20`) and its index (`1`). We ignore the adjacent element because it is greater than `20`. So `20` still holds the record for smallest. Then we move to `5`, which is *smaller* than `20`. Now that `5` is the smallest, we note its index (`3`). Since `18` isn't smaller than so-far-winner (`5`), we ignore it and keep going right. Since `2` is the smallest so far, it is the new winner and its position is noted (`5`). No value smaller than `2` moves right, so that's it. Finally, positions are:

```r
1 # for `20` 
3 # for `5`
5 # for `2`
```

Clearly, the output should always start with `1`, because we never know what comes next.

Another example:

```r
v2 <- c(7, 3, 4, 4, 4, 10, 12, 2, 7, 7, 8)

# output: 
1 2 8
```

`Which.min()` seems to be pretty relevant. But I'm not sure how to use it to get the desired result.

Comment: `which(v1 == cummin(v1))` maybe - how do you want to handle duplicated cumulative minimums?

Comment: @RitchieSacramento when having duplicates return the index of the first duplicating occurrence. As in `v2` above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
which(v1 == cummin(v1))

[1] 1 3 5
```

If you have duplicated cumulative minimums and don't want the duplicates indexed, you can use:

```
which(v1 == cummin(v1) & !duplicated(v1))
```

Or:

```
match(unique(cummin(v1)), v1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the verbose way:

```r
library(purrr)

v1 <- c(20, 30, 5, 18, 2, 10, 8, 4)

v1 %>%
  length() %>%
  seq() %>%
  map_dbl(~ which.min(v1[1: .x])) %>%
  unique()
#> [1] 1 3 5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>